# How to create a sub server inside a main Node.js server

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

How to create sub-servers inside a Node.js main server?

```
const App = express();
const port = 3030;
const Item = require('./script/DBConnector')
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Server is running on port :'+ port)
});
```

Comment: Define what you mean by 'sub servers'.

Comment: What I would suggest you is to write your question such that person wanting to answer would understand it. Give as much as information as you can give regarding the question. Your code seems to have no meaning to the question you are trying to ask plus it's already erroneous as variable `app` is not defined.